# Should the grid header use the same shade as its elements?

Tags: grid, color-scheme

In a **fast-paced** environment (a desktop used by a store, to sell products), should I use a darker color as background for a Grid header, to differentiate the products and the header, or should I use the default **WhiteSmoke** [Header] + **White** [Itens]?

Basically, this: (the default style provided by **WPF**)

[image: Default WhiteSmoke + White]

or this: (Not exactly the same color, size and font, but you get the idea)

[image: Darker headers]

Most of the cases, there will be more elements inside the same window, mostly text fields and buttons (all using a light shade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example ("white smoke"), the header row does not look very different from the rest of the table. On the other hand, this [article about table design for good UX](http://uxmovement.com/content/9-design-techniques-for-user-friendly-tables/) uses "white smoke" but with bold text.

In the second example, with the blue header row, the header row stands out much more. So I prefer the second one. [This article from 2009 uses darker headers](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/09/designing-tables-101.php).

[Most commentators agree that zebra stripes](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=table%20header%20row%20contrast%20ux) make tables much easier to read.

Also, I usually align the table header cell the same as the content that will be in its column (left for words, right for numbers) and so does [this article about design tweaks](http://www.givegoodux.com/ui-design-tweaks-that-make-tables-easier-to-read/).